# Is it possible in SQLAlchemy to define isolation level SNAPSHOT for PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, postgresql, sqlalchemy

My web application uses SQLAlchemy with a PostgreSQL database. Now there is a need to use the equivalent of Microsoft SQL Server's `SNAPSHOT` transaction isolation level, but I did not find a solution in the SQLAlchemy v1.4.44 documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server's “snapshot isolation” [is documented as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server)

> The term "snapshot" reflects the fact that all queries in the transaction see the same version, or snapshot, of the database, based on the state of the database at the moment in time when the transaction begins. No locks are acquired on the underlying data rows or data pages in a snapshot transaction, which permits other transactions to execute without being blocked by a prior uncompleted transaction. Transactions that modify data do not block transactions that read data, and transactions that read data do not block transactions that write data, as they normally would under the default READ COMMITTED isolation level in SQL Server. This non-blocking behavior also significantly reduces the likelihood of deadlocks for complex transactions.
>
> Snapshot isolation uses an optimistic concurrency model. If a snapshot transaction attempts to commit modifications to data that has changed since the transaction began, the transaction will roll back and an error will be raised. You can avoid this by using UPDLOCK hints for SELECT statements that access data to be modified.

That behavior is exactly what you get if you use the transaction isolation level `REPEATABLE READ` in PostgreSQL, so that's what you should use. Note that PostgreSQL always uses multiversioning, so there is no way in PostgreSQL to emulate the read locks that Microsoft SQL server takes for other isolation levels.

Comment: In answering you, I rely on this documentation postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-set-transaction.html and proceed from the description of the behavior of the SERIALIZABLE isolation level - this is the behavior that I want to get. Maybe I'm wrong somewhere because I do not know these subtleties.
Based on your answer, about using READ COMMITTED - is the SNAPSHOT add-on (from the documentation: The SET TRANSACTION SNAPSHOT command allows a new transaction to run with the same snapshot as an existing transaction.) applicable for this transaction so that each transaction has its own table snapshot.

Comment: No, that's something different; it is a way to have several database sessions use the same snapshot. I am sure that SQL Server's snapshot isolation does not have predicate locks like PostgreSQL's `SERIALIZABLE` has.

Comment: Then it turns out to be more correct to use `REPEATABLE READ` and `SET TRANSACTION SNAPSHOT` for state snapshots inside each new transaction

Comment: No, you don't ever use `SET TRANSACTION SNAPSHOT`  unless you need to start several database *sessions* that should share the same snapshot, which you probably cannot even do in SQL Server. Why are you trying to make this more complicated than it fortunately is?

Comment: I am running an application in multiple processes. And I need snapshots of tables to be at the moment of creating a transaction in the first process, provided that the second process has already changed the table.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. The second process that concurrently changes the table is in a different transaction with a different snapshot. So you get a serialization error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right about using `REPEATABLE READ`. I tested everything works as expected